# Where is the camera in OpenGL perspective projection?

Tags: opengl, graphics, perspectivecamera

I'm playing around with openGL and encounter a strange problem. 
[image: point A and B]

Code that defines my frustum:

```
glFrustum(0.0, 50.0, 0.0, 50.0, 5.0, 35.0);
```

Code that generates the polygon and the curve

```
glBegin(GL_POLYGON); // a rectangle
    glVertex3f(20.0, 20.0, -6.0); 
    glVertex3f(20.0, 20.0, -10.0); 
    glVertex3f(20.0, 60.0, -10.0); // point A 
    glVertex3f(20.0, 60.0, -6.0); // point B
glEnd();
glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
for (float i = -PI; i < -PI/3; i += 2 * PI / numSides) {
    glVertex3f(X+14*i, Y + sin(i)*R, -6.0);
}
```

As you can see, even though point B is defined to be closer to the projection screen, its projection onto the Oxz plane is shorter than that of point A. It's almost as if the two points have somehow switched place or that the camera location is behind them and not at (0, 0, 0). Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I dont get it. point A's location(z=-10) is further from the camera than point B's location (z=-6) is, right? Then why is the edge of point A is larger?

Comment: You have not  stated where the camera is. The frustum parameters are specified with respect to _eye space_, but the coordinates in `glVertex` specify _object space_. There is another step transforming from _object space_ to _eye space_ using the `ModelView` matrix, before the projection matrix is applied. Since it is totally unclear how your transformation states are set up, this question is rather unanswerable. Your frustum parameters are also very odd. Furthermore, _every_ single GL function you're using here is _deprecated_ since a decade, and not available in modern OpenGL.

Comment: @derhass is this what you are talking about?  glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
 glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
 glLoadIdentity();
 glFrustum(0.0, 50.0, 0.0, 50.0, 5.0, 35.0);
 //glOrtho(0.0, 100.0, 0.0, 100.0, -1.0, 1.0);
 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
 glLoadIdentity();  I am only beginning openGL, following a book and it tells me to ignore the above block of code so...

Comment: **Your assumption is wrong**. Point A is (20.0, 60.0, -6.0) and Point B is (20.0, 60.0, -10.0) - Use `glFrustum(-60.0, 60.0, -60.0, 60.0, 5.0, 35.0);` to get a better view of the scene, because then the origin of the frustum is in the middle of the window

Comment: @Rabbid76 If that's the case, shouldn't point A be closer to the screen? Since the positive z-axis points out of the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong. Point **A** is at (20.0, 60.0, **-6.0**) and Point **B** is at (20.0, 60.0, **-10.0**).

Use `glFrustum(-60.0, 60.0, -60.0, 60.0, 5.0, 35.0);` to get a better view of the scene, because then the origin of the frustum is in the middle of the window, and extend the quad to a cube, by adding the front and bottom side, to make the scene more spatial:

```
glFrustum(-60.0, 60.0, -60.0, 60.0, 5.0, 35.0);
glLineWidth( 3.0f );
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

glColor4f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glVertex3f(20.0, 20.0, -6.0); 
glVertex3f(60.0, 20.0, -6.0); 
glVertex3f(60.0, 60.0, -6.0); 
glVertex3f(20.0, 60.0, -6.0); 
glEnd();
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glVertex3f(20.0, 20.0, -6.0); 
glVertex3f(60.0, 20.0, -6.0); 
glVertex3f(60.0, 20.0, -10.0);
glVertex3f(20.0, 20.0, -10.0);
glEnd();

glColor4f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glVertex3f(20.0, 20.0, -6.0); 
glVertex3f(20.0, 20.0, -10.0); 
glVertex3f(20.0, 60.0, -10.0);
glVertex3f(20.0, 60.0, -6.0);
glEnd();

const float PI = 3.1415917f;
static float X = 20.0f + PI *14;
static float Y = 60.0f;
static float R = 20.0f;
int numSides = 30;
glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
for (float i = -PI; i < -PI/3; i += 2 * PI / numSides) {
    glVertex3f(X+14*i, Y + sin(i)*R, -6.0);
}
glEnd();
```

See the image, where the magenta cross marks the point of view:

[image]